# Aggregation mongodb to display data on front-end

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm a new student to fullstack JavaScript development.  I'm currently working on a project that produces inventory management information from a food ordering interface.  The current process is that each item ordered is an object that is pushed into an array which represents the full order.

Ex: It goes in as:

```
    {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5751e8c495251b62210242c2"),
    "newMenu" : [
            {
                    "checked" : true,
                    "amount" : 1,
                    "stockNum" : 105,
                    "price" : 11.25,
                    "desc" : "Slow cooked ribs that slide right off the bone. Covered in Jim's special BBQ sauce.",
                    "item" : "Baby Back Ribs"
            },
            {
                    "checked" : true,
                    "amount" : 1,
                    "stockNum" : 107,
                    "price" : 7.85,
                    "desc" : "Delicious pasta stuffed with spinach and ricotta cheese.",
                    "item" : "Raph's Ravioli"
            },
            {
                    "checked" : true,
                    "amount" : 1,
                    "stockNum" : 200,
                    "price" : 1.5,
                    "desc" : "Perpsi, Croke, Mountain Mist, Nurse Pepper, or Spreete.",
                    "item" : "Fountain Drink"
            },
            {
                    "checked" : true,
                    "amount" : 1,
                    "stockNum" : 204,
                    "price" : 5.25,
                    "desc" : "A delicious brown ale from the UK.",
                    "item" : "Oldcastle"
            },
            {
                    "checked" : true,
                    "amount" : 1,
                    "stockNum" : 206,
                    "price" : 4.5,
                    "desc" : "American pale lager.",
                    "item" : "Dudweiser"
            },
            {
                    "checked" : true,
                    "amount" : 1,
                    "stockNum" : 207,
                    "price" : 4.5,
                    "desc" : "Light American pale lager.",
                    "item" : "Dud Light"
            },
            {
                    "checked" : true,
                    "amount" : 1,
                    "stockNum" : 101,
                    "price" : 12.8,
                    "desc" : "Thin crusted pizza with your choice of toppings.",
                    "item" : "New York Pizza"
            }
    ],
    "__v" : 0
 }
```

I need to get the amount of each item ordered based off stock number or `stockNum` and return that value.

So far I've tried:

`db.menus.aggregate([ { $match: { stockNum: "208" } }, {$group: {_id: "$cust_id", total: {$sum: "$amount"}}}, {$sort: {total: -1}}])`

While I get no errors, I also get no output.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't see a document with stockNum : 208. (By the way 208 and "208" are two different things.) Either would be a reason why Mongo is not returning any data.

Comment: pls show correct document of this above query , and i dint see any cust_id in that document